# listBox DataTemplate not picking up values

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I am learning to use listBox in WPF with dataTemplate using the examples from MSDN, I can render a listBox bound to an ObservableCollection as a source and by overriding the ToString method.

However, I need to render an image and some texblocks for every item. Here's my XAML:

```xml
<Grid x:Class="MyAddin.WPFControls"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyAddin"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Background="Transparent"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto"
             Height="215" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <c:People x:Key="MyFriends"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               IsManipulationEnabled="True" 
               Height="20" Width="300">Activity Feed</TextBlock>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="listBox1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
             BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Avatar}" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50" />
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Firstname }" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Comment}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

My Collection class is as following:

```cs
public class People : ObservableCollection<Person>
{ }        

public class Person
{
    private string firstName;
    private string comment;
    private Bitmap avatar;

    public Person(string first, string comment, Bitmap avatar)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string Comment
    {
        get { return comment; }
        set { comment = value; }
    }

    public Bitmap Avatar
    {
        get { return avatar;}
        set { avatar = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return firstName.ToString();
    }
}
```

Once my addin is loaded, I am downloading my data and setting the itemsSource.

```cs
People p = new People();
p.Add(new Person("Willa", "Some Comment", myAvatar));
p.Add(new Person("Isak", "Some Comment", myAvatar));
p.Add(new Person("Victor", "Some Comment", myAvatar));

this.wpfControl.listBox1.ItemsSource = p;
```

The problem I am facing is that the items are being rendered as empty rows whereas If I remove the dataTemplate, the items are rendered fine with their firstName.

Comment: If your person class is supposed to be immutable there a few things you should do: Get rid of the property setters, make the fields `readonly`. If it is not immutable you should implement [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so changes are picked up in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see anything wrong with the bindings themselves, but your avatar type seems off, WPF expects [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) (i do not know if there is any implicit convertion between Bitmap and `ImageSource`, check for [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspxhttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) to find out).

Comment: Turns out it was a spelling mistake! I typed Firstname instead of FirstName. You were also right about the avatar being in an incompatible type. Since my JSON data includes the URL of the avatar, I simply set the Source property of the Image to that :)